# Running a job on mapreduce produces error code 2

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i have problem with speed of MapReduce . Is there any faster library instead of this ?

i tried this for many time but not work as good as we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache Spark Mlib It's 100x faster than MapReduce.